# Android framework debugging

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can we debug to android framework level in Eclipse using SDK? I mean if we are debugging an application eclipse, then can we jump to the java framework code and debug? How do we achieve this on emulator and on device?

Vibgyor

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't.To do this, you must download the whole android source and compile it, add it a java project and remote debug it.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to build the whole android source code in eclipse? I have the source code with me and I can build using the build environment ( outside the Eclipse). While debugging an application, can't I attach the built code and somehow debugger can recognize the framework and jump to framework code??

Comment: yes, This article nicely explains how to accomplish this:[http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very difficult to do this. If you have android sources then when you debug an application and the error "Sources not found" appears, simply push a button attach resources and select path to your folder with android sources. After that you'll have a possibility to debug the sources of Android.